# Permission required to view list of tables in Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I searched SO for a pertinent question existing already but couldn't find one.

I am setting up a Read-only database role for a few databases in our server farm. Here is a sample of the permissions for one table:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
DENY ALTER ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
DENY CONTROL ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
DENY DELETE ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
DENY INSERT ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
DENY REFERENCES ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
DENY TAKE OWNERSHIP ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
DENY UPDATE ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
```

This works as intended for the SELECT permissions...I'm able to **ONLY** SELECT data, which is exactky what I want.

However, I cannot see the list of tables in the "Tables" tab for the specified database in Management Studio. My goal with this user is to provide some users that are unfamiliar with SQL a login they can use to pull data and start experimenting with SQL. These users are experienced with SAS, a statistical processing language, so they have some experience working with code but not so much **specifically** in SQL.

Which of those permissions will show the list of tables in Management Studio?

Comment: This is particularly disturbing...I was under the impression that VIEW DEFINITION was all that was required to view the meta data for the database.

Comment: It is the only permission you need - you're explicitly DENYing other inheritable permissions to the same user, which is overriding the GRANTs (DENY always takes precedence over GRANT). Change to REVOKE, and you'll see the objects in SSMS (see answer below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Granting any permission and view definition is all you need, however you're also explicitly `DENY`ing inheritable permissions from the same user ([DENY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188338.aspx) always overrides a [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)). If you simply do not `GRANT` the permission, they will not have it (alternatively, you can REVOKE rather than `DENY`, which does not explicitly override a `GRANT`). If you change your `DENY`'s to [REVOKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187728.aspx) in the above script, your users will be able to list/view the objects in `SSMS`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to the question - but it do what you need to do:

use the DB_DataReader Role - for the user you want to be read only.
then if you need to further hide some tables from him - just deal with them.

Comment: Excellent...would that be all the tables named "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.***"?

Comment: I think that you might need to grant view definition on more objects for this work, I'm trying to figure out which are them...

Comment: I've edited the answer - the db_datareader role is good choise to create a read only user. that can see the schema, but can't access the tables.