# SQL Server 2008 create tables, invisible in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a database and some tables in C# using .NET SQL Server provider. When I open up SQL Server Management Studio, I see the database; but the tables aren't there. If I run queries from inside my application, the queries return expected results; and SQL Profiler shows the create table commands executing properly. If I cut-n-paste the queries into SQL Server Management Studio, they execute fine, and the table shows up.

I suspect it's a permissions issue; however my .NET application is using SSPI in the connection string, and when I authenticate using SQL Server Management Studio, I am using the logged on windows account creds, so they **should** be using the same credentials.

Do I need to explicitly set the table permission in the SQL call or is my assumption that SSPI is the same as the logged-on windows creds wrong?

Comment: Are you specifying the database name in the connection string, or in the table create statement? Is it possible they're getting created in the wrong database? Look in System Databases\Master, see if they are there.

Comment: SqlACID: yep. Bonehead mistake. Forgot to have the database in the connection string :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as [Permission required to view list of tables in Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709150/permission-required-to-view-list-of-tables-in-management-studio). http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/9507f18c-7175-40dc-93e4-a7e236b9aa46.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- does the account have permissions to the schema the new tables are in?
- have you refreshed the Tables directory in SSMS? (Silly, I know)

Comment: I did do a refresh; but perhaps it takes time? They are very basic tables with a limited amount of data. Wouldn't the account that creates the tables have privs to schema by default? If not, thats likely my issue!