# Some users cannot access view containing tables from different database in SQL Server 2012 - error Msg 916

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

Hello Stackoverflow experts

I've decided to ask for your help in very strange issue I face in SQL Server 2012.

There are 2 databases - `DB1` and `DB2`. Two logins defined - `login1` and `login2`, both using Windows Authentication. Their settings are identical in all possible matters - same role (public), same permissions (only CONNECT and VIEW ANY DATABASE) - mapped to different users on DB1 (user 1 to login1 and user2 to login2)

Now the funny thing comes. There is a view on `DB1` defined as simple

```
SELECT * FROM [DB2].[TABLE1]
```

This view has privileges defined identical for both user1 and user2, all columns. User1 can view the data using simple SELECT statement, user2 cannot. Both have `SELECT` ticked as GRANT. User2 gets the following message:

> Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   The server principal 'User2' is not able to access the database 'DB2' under the current security context

I went through all possible properties, privileges, queried sysusers, permissions tables - both users and logins are identical, it's like one would be a copy of another with a different name.

Googling the stuff I must eliminate the following possibilities:

- orphaned users (as both user1 and user2 were created and properly assigned)
- none of the databases were migrated from anywhere, so this is not an ownership issue definitely

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[DB2].[TABLE1]` different DBs or different schemas?

Comment: Different DBs. It is like: DB1 has view V1, which has statement of SELECT * FROM [DB2].TABLE1]

Comment: The symptoms suggests User2 is not a user in DB2 but User1 is, either directly or via Windows group membership. It could also be that User2 doesn't have CONNECT permissions in the DB2 database.

Comment: Hi Dan. In fact we say about logins, since users 1 and 2 are present in DB1 only, they are not defined in DB2. The logins for both users have CONNECT SQL and VIEW ANY DATABASE permissions. Could you please elaborate a bit more on "via Windows group membership" ? I didn't see any Windows group defined on the DB2-level

Answer (score 0):

If user 1 has access to the view/table is inherited, but user2 doesn't have access to the BD1 that user1 already has. Perhaps, you should manually give access user2 to see view/table in DB1

So for user2 could be a script like the following

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[Table] TO [ReadOnly]
```

Another thing to consider is that DENY overrides GRANT, so it won't matter if you grant permission for user2 on DB1 if there is a DENY on some level above the view for user2, in this case you should use REVOKE

take a look at the following link in stackoverflow 
[Permission required to view list of tables in Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709150/permission-required-to-view-list-of-tables-in-management-studio)

Comment: Thanks for this response. Unfortunately there is no DENY at any level for these two users, neither on the View, nor in the Roles or the User/Login itself. I have also verified, that there is no restriction on the inherited Public role